# PageSpeed Insights で発生したコントラストエラーの原因と調査の仕方がわからない

Tags: css

PageSpeed Insightsのユーザ補助コントラストの箇所で

!「背景色と前景色には十分なコントラスト比があります」エラー

と表示され何が原因なのかが分からないのですが「！」エラーの場合はどのように調査すればいいのでしょうか。
赤い▲ではなく!のエラーです。

CSSにエラーがないかはチェック済です。

[image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: 他のユーザーが再現できるよう、質問に関連するコードを本文に追記してください。

Comment: 質問の意図がわからないです。表示されてるメッセージの意味がわからないのか、意味はわかるが指摘を受ける理由がわからないのか、それともそれ以外の何かなのか、第三者にも意図が伝わるよう具体的に説明してください。「編集」リンクから追記したり書き直したりできます。

Comment: クリックして展開すると、詳しい内容が読めたりはしませんか？

Answer (score -1):

色の設定でハイコントラストな設定になっているのではないのでしょうか。
色の明るいところと暗いところの差が大きいのだと思います。